# Intercepting an application's call stack

Tags: php, c

I'm trying to explore options to monitor running applications with a view to determining and predicting the resources that they need, for research purposes. I am familiar with PHP so I thought I would start by trying to monitor a running PHP application. Some searching shows that New Relic does this with a PHP extension/module.

I started reading up on PHP extensions, but I can't find any code samples or instructions to intercept the call stack like how New Relic does it. I want to write some prototype code to log the call stack in a machine-readable format. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

It's important that this is done in an application-generic way, which is why I was looking at a module.

Comment: Take a look at the xdebug extension, it may be easier

Comment: Xdebug is a good call but possibly a bit overkill? I'll be interested to see what other options are available.

Comment: Many apps have more than one stack, so you may have problems.

Comment: In fact, only two processes out of 76 on my box have only one stack.

Answer (score 0):

Pure PHP obviously cannot have a look at the call stack since you can't get direct memory access, this part will have to be done with C/C++ and if you still insist on using PHP then you will need to turn this code into a library or a PHP extension, but is sounds as if you already have one that does this.

Comment: I know - I am looking into writing an extension in C.

Comment: maybe the gdb code could help, they look at debugs a lot.
Or you could look at the source code for "debug_backtrace" in the php open source.